# ¿Qué lenguaje de programación o framework de javascript es este?

Tags: javascript

Buenas a todos, como el título indica, me gustaría saber a que lenguaje de programación hace parte el siguiente código.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require("electron");
const Menu = require("./menu");

app.on("ready", () => {
    Menu.buildMenu();

let window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1128,
    height: 649,
    plugins: true
});
    window.loadURL("file://" + __dirname + "/public/index.html");
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    app.quit();
});
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese código corresponde al **Framework** `Electron`.

> Es un framework que te permite crear aplicaciones de escritorio, con base en tecnologías web como Javascript, CSS y HTML.

Su sitio oficial es https://electron.atom.io

Answer (score -1):

El lenguaje de programación que se está usando es JavaScript, concretamente ECMAScript 6/ES6.

En cuanto al framework, está usando  [electron](https://electron.atom.io). Es un framework para crear Apps de escritorio multi plataforma con JavaScript, HTML y CSS